# GCMTaskManager PeriodicTask... restart timer and/or see how much time is left?

Tags: android, periodic-task, gcmtaskservice

I am trying to use the GCMTaskManager to schedule a periodic task that runs approximately every 30 minutes.  When it runs, it does an "update" on some internal data in the APP.

I have this preliminarily running and can see, using a `LOG` command in the `OnRunTask`, that the task fires as desired.I have it operating (at least according to a LOG I am populating when the `OnRunTask` fires.

I have two issues I can't determine if it can be done....

- Is there a way to see how much time is "left" before the next `OnRunTask` fires... or... approximately what "time" it should run next?   Example, if there is 30 minutes for the PeriodTask... and 18 minutes have lapsed, can we programmatically see that 12 minutes remain?
- I have an internal "button" to manual fire the APPS update.   If the user hits this, I want to "restart" the PeriodicTask timer from that point.   That is, if the 30 minute `OnRunTask` is suppose to fire in approximately 12 minutes, and the user hits the UPDATE manually, I want the `OnRunTask` to now restart from for 30 minutes from the button press.  Can this be done?

Thanks

Pete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1) GCMNetworkManager does not provide an interface for keeping track of the time elapsed/remaining but you can do so yourself by maintaining a variable storing the last updated timestamp for your data.

2) From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/network-manager)

> When Google Play Services or the client app is updated, all scheduled tasks are removed. GcmNetworkManager invokes the client app’s onInitializeTasks(). Override this function to reschedule necessary tasks.